# Exportin data from Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I am exporting data from Matrix in Power BI to excel (csv). The problem is that these data are showing in excel in one column separated by commas. My colleagues don't have this issues. If they export data they are separated into columns based on header in matrix. Where should I fix this? Is it some Power BI settings or excel? I don't want to always use text to columns because (use comma as separator), because my $values are messed up.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change the regional settings in the PowerBI file.

Click File->Options and Settings->Current File->Regional Settings and adjust accordingly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by Changing Regional Setting in Windows.